# Why do I get this TypeScript error when using Firebase Firestore withConverter()?

Tags: typescript, firebase

I'm trying to use the Firebase Firestore `withConverter()` method for JavaScript Version 9 SDK.

My code is an adaptation of [this tutorial](https://medium.com/swlh/using-firestore-with-typescript-65bd2a602945).

The basic idea is that we can use `withConverter()` to add TypeScript typings for Firestore document data.

The main difference between my code and the tutorial is that the tutorial uses `import { firestore } from "firebase-admin"` and `firestore().collection()` which comes from the Admin SDK for secure environments. While I am using `import { collection } from 'firebase/firestore';` to the same effect for the front end.

And my problem is that my code is throwing a TypeScript error.

Here's my code:

```TypeScript
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { collection, getFirestore, PartialWithFieldValue, QueryDocumentSnapshot } from 'firebase/firestore';

// Firestore setup
const firebaseConfig = {
  ...
};
const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const firestore = getFirestore(firebaseApp);

// Making the converter
const converter = <T>() => ({
  toFirestore: (data: PartialWithFieldValue<T>) => data,
  fromFirestore: (snap: QueryDocumentSnapshot) => snap.data() as T,
});

// This works without error, "userColRef" is correctly typed as "CollectionReference<User>"
const userColRef = collection(firestore, 'users').withConverter(converter<User>());

// This throws an error
const dataPoint = <T>(collectionPath: string) => {
  return collection(firestore, collectionPath).withConverter(converter<T>()); // <-- ERROR HERE
};
```

Here is the TypeScript error on `converter<T>()`:

```TypeScript
No overload matches this call.   Overload 1 of 2, '(converter: null): CollectionReference<DocumentData>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ toFirestore: (data: PartialWithFieldValue<T>) => PartialWithFieldValue<T>; fromFirestore: (snap: QueryDocumentSnapshot) => T; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'null'.   Overload 2 of 2, '(converter: FirestoreDataConverter<T>): CollectionReference<T>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ toFirestore: (data: PartialWithFieldValue<T>) => PartialWithFieldValue<T>; fromFirestore: (snap: QueryDocumentSnapshot) => T; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FirestoreDataConverter<T>'.
      The types returned by 'toFirestore(...)' are incompatible between these types.
        Type 'PartialWithFieldValue<T>' is not assignable to type 'DocumentData'.
          Type 'T extends Primitive ? T : T extends {} ? { [K in keyof T]?: FieldValue | PartialWithFieldValue<T[K]> | undefined; } : never' is not assignable to type 'DocumentData'.
            Type 'T | (T extends {} ? { [K in keyof T]?: FieldValue | PartialWithFieldValue<T[K]> | undefined; } : never)' is not assignable to type 'DocumentData'.
              Type 'Primitive & T' is not assignable to type 'DocumentData'.
                Type 'undefined & T' is not assignable to type 'DocumentData'.ts(2769)
```

More details about `withConverter()` can be found [here in the offical docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.firestoredataconverter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.

I added a new `WithId` intersection type because I am also using VueFire and it adds a new `id` property to all documents. Having this solved the issue above, although I'm not exactly sure *why* the error went away. But it's gone now.

I also updated `fromFirestore: (snap: QueryDocumentSnapshot) => snap.data() as T` to the more correct `fromFirestore: (snap: QueryDocumentSnapshot<T>) => snap.data()`.

Here is the full code:

```TypeScript
type WithId<T> = T & { id: string };

const converter = <T>() => ({
  toFirestore: (data: PartialWithFieldValue<T>) => data,
  fromFirestore: (snap: QueryDocumentSnapshot<T>) => snap.data(),
});

const dataPoint = <T>(collectionPath: string) => {
  return collection(firestore, collectionPath).withConverter(
    converter<WithId<T>>()
  );
};
```

**UPDATE:**

If you don't want to use `WithId<T>` it can also be done like this:

```TypeScript
const converter = <T>(): FirestoreDataConverter<T> => ({
  toFirestore: (data: PartialWithFieldValue<T>) => data as DocumentData,
  fromFirestore: (snap: QueryDocumentSnapshot<DocumentData>) =>
    snap.data() as T,
});

const dataPoint = <T>(collectionPath: string) => {
  return collection(firestore, collectionPath).withConverter(
    converter<T>()
  );
};
```

This also works:

```TypeScript
const converter = <T>() => ({
  toFirestore: (data: PartialWithFieldValue<T>) => data,
  fromFirestore: (snap: QueryDocumentSnapshot<T>) => snap.data(),
});

const dataPoint = <T extends DocumentData>(collectionPath: string) => {
  return collection(firestore, collectionPath).withConverter(
    converter<T>()
  );
};
```